# Parse arrays using Plossum CommandLine in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use the `Plossum CommandLine` parser to parse arrays in `C#`, but it doesn't seem to work.

The following code is a stripped-down version of an example I found in the source code somewhere:

```
using Plossum.CommandLine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PlossumCommandLine
{
    [CommandLineManager(ApplicationName = "Example 2", Copyright = "Copyright (C) Peter Palotas 2007",
EnabledOptionStyles = OptionStyles.Group | OptionStyles.LongUnix)]
    [CommandLineOptionGroup("commands", Name = "Commands", Require = OptionGroupRequirement.ExactlyOne)]
    [CommandLineOptionGroup("options", Name = "Options")]
    class Options
    {
        [CommandLineOption(Name = "filter", RequireExplicitAssignment = true,
            Description = "Specifies a filter on which files to include or exclude", GroupId = "options")]
        public List<string> Filters
        {
            get { return mFilters; }
            set { mFilters = value; }
        }

        [CommandLineOption(Name = "h", Aliases = "help", MinOccurs = 0, Description = "Shows this help text", GroupId = "commands")]
        public bool Help
        {
            get { return mHelp; }
            set { mHelp = value; }
        }

        private bool mHelp;

        private List<string> mFilters = new List<string>();
    }
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Options options = new Options();
            CommandLineParser parser = new CommandLineParser(options);
            parser.Parse();

            if (options.Help)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(parser.UsageInfo.ToString(78, false));
                return 0;
            }
            else if (parser.HasErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(parser.UsageInfo.ToString(78, true));
                return -1;
            }

            // No errors present and all arguments correct 
            // Do work according to arguments   
            Console.WriteLine("Filters: " + string.Join(",", options.Filters.ToArray()));
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The syntaxed I used to call the above code is:

```
program.exe --filter abc
```

And the result is:

```
Example 2  version 1.0.0.0
Copyright (C) Peter Palotas 2007

Errors:
   * Missing required value for option "filter"
   * One of the options "h" must be specified

Commands:
   -h, --help    Shows this help text

Options:
   --filter      Specifies a filter on which files to include or exclude
```

My system:

VS: 2015
OS: Win 7 x64
.NET: 4
Plossum: The one from nuGet

I probably just cannot see the wall in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

With the option `OptionStyles.LongUnix` the command line should be:

```
program.exe --filter=abc
```